# How can i make this Keyfunction and onload function to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i using this code to highlight the input value when window on load and keyup

Currently only keyup is working - not works when the window is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".titleinput").keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length > 10) {
            $(this).css("color", "red");
        } else {
            $(this).css("color", "#555");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo : https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/QxqJmg

JS

```
var init = function () {  
    if ($('.titleinput').val().length > 10) {
        $('.titleinput').css("color", "red");
    } else {
        $('.titleinput').css("color", "orange");
    }
}

window.onload = init;
$(".titleinput").keyup(init);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help - but when i open the window it wont do anything

Comment: When you open the window, text color is orange and when type it changes to red once length is greater than 10. Also, once your issue fixed, accept and upvote answer!!

Comment: If default value more than 10 - When open the window  - its still stay  orange instead of red

Comment: Hi, i have clicked accepted but its shows https://screenshots.firefox.com/ss2dOMOQD0rmGwY0/stackoverflow.com